# have a div push-up from bottom of html panel but not on top of body text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have seen a "push-down" notice coming from the top, as in this site:

http://www.yokogawa.com

Notice that it pushes the other content down, not lays on top of it.

What I want to do seems a bit trickier but I hope possible.  I would like to have an info bar push up, and not be considered part of the scrollable area.

In other words, suppose the viewport is 500px high, and the 50px info bar pushes "up".  The scrollable area of the viewport would be 450px high, and the scrollbar height on the right goes from 0 to 450px.

So in effect, the *scrollable* viewport reduces from the bottom, and when scrolled all the way down, the bottom of the page content is right on the top of the info bar.

I'm concerned with animating it but would first like to see the CSS of such a div in position.

Answer (score 0):

Add the style "position: absolute" to your "push-down".